# Why does an event emitted by a smart contract function called via `delegateCall` disappear?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, rsk

I have two interacting smart contracts that I am developing/testing in Hardhat and deploying to [RSK](https://developers.rsk.co/):

1. `DelegateCallee` smart contract with a `getData()` function, emitting a `Received` event:

```
contract DelegateCallee {
  event Received(address sender, uint value);
  function getData() external payable {
    emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
  }
}
```

2. `DelegateCaller` smart contract which uses Solidity's `delegateCall` to invoke `getData()` from the `DelegateCallee`:

```
contract DelegateCaller {
  address callee;

  constructor(address _callee) {
    callee = _callee;
  }

  function delegateCallGetData() external payable {
    (bool success, ) = callee.delegatecall(
      abi.encodeWithSelector(DelegateCallee.getData.selector)
    );
    require(success, "delegate call failed");
  }
}
```

I am running Hardhat tests to intercept the events emitted by `DelegateCallee`. When I am invoking `getData()` directly on the `DelegateCallee`, the event is being emitted as expected:

```js
  it('getData function on callee should emit the Received event', async () => {
    const value = ethers.utils.parseEther('1');
    const tx = await delagateCallee.getData({ value });
    await expect(tx)
      .to.emit(delagateCallee, 'Received')
      .withArgs(deployer.address, value);
  });
```

```bash
  Low level calls
    ✔ getData function on callee should emit the Received event
```

However when I use the `DelegateCaller` contract,
invoking its `delegateCallGetData()`,
which in turn invokes the `DelegateCallee` contract's
`getData()` function, the `Received` event is not emitted.

```js
  it('delegateCallGetData function on caller should emit the Received event on the callee', async () => {
    const value = ethers.utils.parseEther('1');
    const tx = await delegateCaller.delegateCallGetData({ value });
    await expect(tx)
      .to.emit(delagateCallee, 'Received')
      .withArgs(deployer.address, value);
  });
```

```
  1) Low level calls
       delegateCallGetData function on caller should emit the Received event on the callee:
     AssertionError: Expected event "Received" to be emitted, but it wasn't
```

Where is my event lost?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, the `Received` event is there, though Hardhat doesn't recognise it as a `DelegateCallee` event. This happens because you are invoking the function via `delegateCall`. Waffle/ Hardhat expects the event emitter to be the `DelegateCallee` smart contract, but due to the fact that the function was called in the context of another smart contract, the `DelegateCaller` was probably registered as an emitter. To make sure, you should try the following:

1. Get the transaction receipt:

```js
const tx = await delegateCaller.delegateCallGetData({ value });
const receipt = await tx.wait();
```

2. Find an event emitted by the caller (not the callee)

```js
const event = receipt.events.find(
    (e) => e.address === delegateCaller.address,
);
```

3. Use `interface.decodeEventLog()` (from ethers.js) to decode this event's parameters

```js
const decodedEvent = delagateCallee.interface.decodeEventLog(
    'Received',
    event.data,
    event.topics,
);
```

4. Use assertions to verify the received values
   The whole test should look something like this:

```js
it('should emit on the callee', async () => {
    const value = ethers.utils.parseEther('1');
    const tx = await delegateCaller.delegateCallGetData({ value });
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    const event = receipt.events.find(
      (e) => e.address === delegateCaller.address,
    );
    const decodedEvent = delagateCallee.interface.decodeEventLog(
      'Received',
      event.data,
      event.topics,
    );
    expect(decodedEvent.sender).to.equal(deployer.address);
    expect(decodedEvent.value).to.equal(value);
});
```

Comment: This is great insight